# Prevent python from adding backslashes to string

Tags: python, backslash

**Set-up**

I have a pandas DataFrame `df`.

For each row in `df['district']` I create a `temp` string which I append to list `sl1`.

Subsequently, I add two strings to each `temp` in `sl1` and append the result to a second list `sl2`.

I do this in the following way,

```
sl1 = []
for key, value in df['district'].iteritems():
    temp = "http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/zuid+holland/agglomeratie+'s-gravenhage/'s-gravenhage"
    sl1.append(temp)    

sl2 = []
for link in sl1:
    x = '<a href="' + link + '">'
    sl2.append(x)
```

---

**Issue**

In the second for loop, something strange occurs. In stead of obtaining an `sl2` filled with rows containing,

```
'<a href="http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/zuid+holland/agglomeratie+'s-gravenhage/'s-gravenhage">'
```

the rows are filled with,

```
'<a href="http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/zuid+holland/agglomeratie+\'s-gravenhage/\'s-gravenhage">'
```

How come Python adds those backslashes, and more importantly:

How can I prevent/remove them?

Does it have to do with the `'` in `'s-gravenhage`?

Comment: The backslashes are not part of the string. They're just how Python represents the fact that the apostrophe doesn't close the string. There is no reason for you to change anything here.

Comment: Don't confuse the *representation* (which has to be a valid string literal) with the value. Those backslashes are required only when re-creating the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, this is just representation of the value. Those backslashes are just escape characters for the single quote `'`.

If you print x or write it to a file, you'd see that the output is just fine.

```
temp = "http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/zuid+holland/agglomeratie+'s-gravenhage/'s-gravenhage"
x = '<a href="' + temp + '">'
print(x)
```

This returns `<a href="http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/zuid+holland/agglomeratie+'s-gravenhage/'s-gravenhage">` as expected.

Comment: I like cabbage.

Comment: @LucSpan I like how you split your questions into set-up and problem. :)